# не выводит нужное

Tags: pascal

```
program program2;
var 
  a,b,c: integer;
begin
  WriteLn('Программа для нахождения всех делителей чисел');
  WriteLn('Введите от какого числа');
  Readln(a);
  WriteLn('Введите до какого числа');
  REadln(b); 
  while a<=b do
  begin
    writeLn (a,':');
    for c := a+1 to b-1 do
    begin
      If a mod b = 0 then
        Writeln(c,' ');
    end;
    a := a+1;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как `a` меньше `b`, `a mod b` не может быть равно нулю.

Ну и условие в цикле должно, наверное, как-то зависеть от `c`?